Avatar Axis suddnley changed

I made character and rigged by rigify, and made pose in dope sheet.
But sometimes, avatar modeling's axis changes weired like this.

I can fix it by setting character modelings to specific position and rotation like this.
If I press alt+PRS in modeling, than modeling goes to weired position again...
Why this happens?

Hello it's hard to understand, could you please share your file? Remove all the unnecessary elements

You have Auto Keying enabled in the middle of the Timeline header. Could it be that you are moving something and then moving to another frame which will cause a keyframe to be inserted?
